# Tab bar icon too large in Xcode 5

Tags: interface-builder, storyboard, ios7, xcode5

I have a problem with the Tab Bar. After two days I opened my Xcode and icons Tab Bar have widened.

I have tried to delete and insert a new TabBar Controller but it did not solve the problem. I have also created a new project but it has the same problem. This problem is also reflected in the simulator.

Is there a way to fix this?

[Screenshot of my TabBar Controller](http://i40.tinypic.com/2u6zomw.png)

Comment: Xcode doesn't change things while you're away. Have you tried setting the itemWidth property on the tab bar?

Comment: This is my item settings:
Badge: nothing
Identifier: custom
Title: Default Position
Title(text): Transaction
Image:nothing (for now)
Tag:0
  What you mean itemWhidt, i not have provided any code for now

Comment: I have try to create a new project and i have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those sizes look about right according to the [new Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21). I'm guessing the Xcode placeholder view just defaults to the maximum possible size icon (96x64 retina). If you just resize your icon images appropriately and set the [`itemPositioning`, `itemWidth` and `itemSpacing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html) to the values you want, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding @2x to your image name (e.g. TabBarImage@2x.png)

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same issue, the solution I found is to use two icons, one of 30x30 pixel icons and another 60X60 both have the same name, the larger file with @2x

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm running with XCode 6.4. You'll need to add those images into `images.xcassets` and include the `@2x` and `@3x` files accordingly based on the dimensions provided here:

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2)

Comment: I didn't name the retina version with `@2x` and it works just fine until Xcode 10.  Once I rename the images with `@2x`, `@3x`, the tab bar icons appears just fine in Storyboard.  This isn't necessary for other image assets (at least I've encounter problem with other images)

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your icons so they are smaller?